# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, android, listview

i have problem when im trying to show data in list view from my database
the error is "**FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4**"
. i dont understand what is it.

i hope somebody can help me
thanks

this is my code

> public class FragmentMaintain extends Fragment {
>
> ```
> ListView list;
> TextView mid;
> TextView pid;
> TextView status;
> TextView description;
> TextView note;
> ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
> //URL to get JSON Array
> private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/skripsi/json/testing.php";
>
> //JSON Node Names
> private static final String TAG_OS = "maintenance";
> private static final String TAG_MID = "mid";
> private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
> private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
> private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
> private static final String TAG_NOTE = "note";
> JSONArray maintenance = null;
> Button Addnotedata;
>
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     Log.d("ZZZ", "ada di oncreateView maintain");
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maintain, container, false);
>
>     new JSONParse().execute();
>     return rootView;
>
>
> }
>
>
> private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
>     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
>     @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         super.onPreExecute();
>         mid = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mid);
>         pid = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pid);
>         status = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.status);
>         description = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.description);
>         note = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.note);
>
>         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
>         pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
>         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>         pDialog.setCancelable(true);
>         pDialog.show();
>     }
>     @Override
>     protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
>         //String pid = getArguments().getString("pid");
>         //List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>         //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
>         JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
>         JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequestWithoutParams(url);
>         //Log.d("TES", pid+", "+ json.toString());
>         return json;
>     }
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
>         pDialog.dismiss();
>         try {
>             // Getting JSON Array from URL
>             maintenance = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
>             for(int i = 0; i < maintenance.length(); i++){
>                 JSONObject c = maintenance.getJSONObject(i);
>                 // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
>                 String mid = c.getString(TAG_MID);
>                 String pid = c.getString(TAG_PID);
>                 String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
>                 String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
>                 String note = c.getString(TAG_NOTE);
>                 // Adding value HashMap key => value
>                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
>                 map.put(TAG_MID, mid);
>                 map.put(TAG_PID, pid);
>                 map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
>                 map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
>                 map.put(TAG_NOTE, note);
>                 oslist.add(map);
>                 list=(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
>                 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,
>                         R.layout.list_maintain,
>                         new String[] { TAG_MID,TAG_PID, TAG_STATUS, TAG_NOTE}, new int[] {
>                         R.id.mid,R.id.pid, R.id.status, R.id.description, R.id.note});
>                 list.setAdapter(adapter);
>                 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
>                                             int position, long id) {
>                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " + oslist.get(+position).get("pid"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
>         } catch (JSONException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

and this my logcat

> 10-10 00:10:50.575    2004-2004/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
>               at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:160)
>               at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
>               at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
>               at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
>               at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
>               at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
>               at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)

Comment: Look at your Adapter instantiation. The arrays for the data keys and the View IDs are different sizes.

Comment: What is +position in oslist.get(+position).get("pid"); ? and ur String[] and int[] is not matching

Comment: `FragmentMaintain` is *not* listed in your stack trace. You need to post the code that causing the problem.

Comment: I think you missing TAG_DESCRIPTION in String Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,R.layout.list_maintain,new String[] {TAG_MID,TAG_PID,TAG_STATUS,TAG_DESCRIPTION,TAG_NOTE}, new int[] { R.id.mid,R.id.pid, R.id.status, R.id.description, R.id.note});
```

You are missing to pass TAG_DESCRIPTION in String Array at adapter initialization.

Answer (score 1):

If the length is 4, max index should be 3 as the index starts from 0.

Comment: This should be comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you create SimpleAdapter the 4th and 5th arguments need to be same size.

So strings of 4th argument will be used as keys to fill view with value of the map which is 3rd argument of constructor.

And the way matching a view with a key is specifying them in 4th and 5th arguments which are containing keys and containing ids of views respectively, to have same index in each array.

[See this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter(android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[]))